# Track leaflet draw polygon changes

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

Question: In Leaflet.draw is there an event to tell if shape of a polygon has changed?

The scenario of my problem is when a user changes the shape of a polygon and hits the cancel button I want to prompt the user with a confirmation if he/she wants to discard the changes.